# How do I trigger Stripe Credit Card Checkout with an anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, stripe-payments

**Background**

I am trying to integrate Stripe into our website. The checkout page has two button options, PayPal or Visa/Credit Card.

This is the code at the moment.

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-paypal" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-paypal" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        PayPal
    </a>
    <form action="<?php echo base_url() . 'stripe/process'; ?>" method="POST">
        <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"
        class="stripe-button"
        data-key="xxxx"
        data-image="your site image"
        data-name="w3code.in"
        data-description="Demo Transaction ($100.00)"
        data-amount="10000" />
        </script>
    </form>
</div>
```

It produces this...

[image]

The button and everything works perfectly... however I want it to look like this.

[image]

The code looks like this...

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-paypal" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-paypal" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        PayPal
    </a>
    <a type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-stripe">
        Visa/Credit Card
        <i class="fa fa-cc-stripe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

I am wondering if there is a way to make the clicking of the `<a>` anchor tag sort of trigger the form (perhaps a hidden form).

I have a vague idea of how this might work so I will try my best to show you guys what I have attempted...

**My Attempt**

I removed the `stripe-button` class from the script tags and added `onclick="document.getElementById('stripe').submit();"` to my new anchor tag to submit the form, however this does not have the same effect.

```
<a type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-stripe" href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('stripe').submit();">
    Visa/Credit Card
    <i class="fa fa-cc-stripe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
<form id="stripe" action="<?php echo base_url() . 'stripe/process'; ?>" method="POST">
    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"
    data-key="xxx"
    data-image="your site image"
    data-name="w3code.in"
    data-description="Demo Transaction ($100.00)"
    data-amount="10000" />
    </script>
</form>
```

The original stripe button that is displayed by the  tag is showing the stripe popup window **before** the form is submitted... how do I trigger the same process with my anchor tag?

Where am I going wrong?

**UPDATE-1:**

Still not working unfortunately... here is what I have tried...

```
<a type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-stripe" onclick="document.getElementByClass('stripe-button').submit();">
    Visa/Credit Card
    <i class="fa fa-cc-stripe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
<form action="<?php echo base_url() . 'stripe/process'; ?>" method="POST">
    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"
    class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_uT2PnISTl40vQWojZAngFlu6"
    data-image="your site image"
    data-name="w3code.in"
    data-description="Demo Transaction ($100.00)"
    data-amount="10000" />
    </script>
</form>
```

Comment: maybe try a click event, so hide the stripe button, put a div/anchor whatever in its place, and on click of the dummy button fire a click event on the stripe button so that checkou tform pops up

Comment: Hi could you perhaps elaborate? I already have an onclick event to trigger the form, but I need to trigger the script instead...

Comment: Great idea, trying that now.

Comment: If not, you could always use custom stripe forms instead which give you more flexibility

Comment: Updated my OP, unfortunately it is still not triggering the pop-up.

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/custom-form this should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far virepo! Just looking at it now. All the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Checkout's ["custom integration"](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom), which will allow you to use your own button with the style you want, and use JavaScript to bind the Checkout's popup to the button's click event.

Comment: Stripe just makes it so easy...this is exactly what I was after. Thanks!